# Javascript Conditional Execution Flow

Tags: javascript

If I have a simple conditional in my function (in the example below), would `doFinalCheck()` always be executed last? If `doThis()` or `doThat()` are API requests and would take a bit of time to complete, would `doFinalCheck()` get executed before the API requests?

```
checkSomething(array){
  if (array){
    doThis();
  }
  else {
    doThat();
  }
  doFinalCheck();
}
```

Comment: Depends on how doThis and doThat are implemented. And if they throw an exception. There's no general answer other than "it depends": implementation is everything.

Comment: There is start and end of execution of a function. If this/that doesn't do anything asynchronously, it's guaranteed order this -> that -> final. But if they do, there's no guarantee that this or that will finish sooner than final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...would `doFinalCheck()` always be executed last?

Yes, unless `doThis()`/`doThat()` throws an exception. But keep reading.

> If `doThis()` or `doThat()` are API requests and would take a bit of time to complete, would `doFinalCheck()` get executed before the API requests?

It depends on whether `doThis()` and/or `doThat()` are *synchronous* or *asynchronous*.

If they're *synchronous*, yes, `onFinalCheck()` will wait until they're done.

If they're *asynchronous*, `onFinalCheck()` will wait until the `doThis()`/`doThat()` call is done, but that call just **starts** the process. The process then continues and completes asynchronously. So `onFinalCheck()` will get called before the process is complete.

If you're dealing with asynchronous operations, look at [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and the new (ES2018) [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

For instance, **if** `doThis()`/`doThat()` are asynchronous and **if** they return a promise, then you can make `onFinalCheck()` wait for the operation to complete like this:

```
    // I assume this is in an object initializer or `class`
    async checkSomething(array){
//  ^^^^^
      if (array){
        await doThis();
//      ^^^^^
      }
      else {
        await doThat();
//      ^^^^^
     }
      doFinalCheck();
    }
```

Like all `async` functions, `checkSomething` will return a promise.

Or if for some reason you can't use an `async` function, but you can use promises and `doThis()`/`doThat()` return promises, then:

```
// I assume this is in an object initializer or `class`
checkSomething(array){
  return (array ? doThis() : doThat())
      .then(result => {
          doFinalCheck();
          return result;
      });
}
```

Note that `checkSomething` returns a promise above. If nothing is going to use that promise, then don't return and put an error check inline:

```
// I assume this is in an object initializer or `class`
checkSomething(array){
  return (array ? doThis() : doThat())
      .then(result => {
          doFinalCheck();
      })
      .catch(error => {
          // ...handle/report the error...
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `doThis()` and `doThat()` are async (such as network requests), then `doFinalCheck()` will execute immediately after the network requests are initiated, but before the request actually finishes.

If they are async, you'll need them to return a `Promise` (or have a callback). You can also use the `await` and `async` syntax (which is just syntactical sugar on the `Promise`.